# enable special keys in lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, xmodmap, openbox, lxsession

I've done a lot of reading and cannot find a simple answer to what seems like it should be a simple question. How do I define the functions of the extra keys such as the "my computer" and "web browser" keys?

Here's what I've done so far.

1. Install LUbuntu 14.04
2. Run xev to cap keycode for "Web/Home" button (180)
3. Run xmodmap -jke to get keysym (XF86HomePage)
4. edited .config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml to include:

`<!-- Keybinding for WebHome button-->
<keybind key="XF86HomePage">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>lxsession-default webbrowser</command>
  </action>
</keybind>`

1. relog
2. press "Web/Home" button
3. lxsession exits to login screen

The default web browser in LXSession configuration -> Launching applications is set to x-www-browser and the "Web Browser" button on the Application Launch Bar works perfectly.

Pressing the "Web/Home" button prior to making any changes does absolutely nothing. It does not exit to the login screen.

The volume buttons work fine "out of the box" but the calculator button is keycode 140 and mapped to keysym SunFront. Pressing it exits to the login screen as well and attempting to reprogram it following the steps above also results in exiting to the login screen.

This process is extremely opaque with very few references/howtos on how to get this working "out of the box" on a fresh Ubuntu install. Any help would be greatly appreciated.